# How to use categorical data type with pyarrow dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas, types, pyarrow, dtype

**I'm working with the arrow dtypes with pandas**, and my dataframe has a variable that should be categorical, **but I can't figure out how to transform it into pyarrow data type for categorical data (dictionary)**

According to pandas (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html#pandas-arrow-conversion), the arrow data type I should be using is dictionary.

Usually, if you want pandas to use a pyarrow dtype you just add[pyarrow] to the name of the pyarrow type, for example dtype='string[pyarrow]'. **I tried using dtype='dictionary[pyarrow]', but that yields the error:**

> data type 'dictionary[pyarrow]' not understood

I also tried 'categorical[pyarrow]', or 'category[pyarrow]', pyarrow.dictionary, pyarrow.dictionary(pyarrow.int16(),pyarrow.string()), and they didn't work either.

How can i use dictionary dtype on a pandas series?
pd.Series(['Chocolate','Candy','Waffles'], dtype='what_to_put_here????')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [`pd.ArrowDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.ArrowDtype.html#pandas.ArrowDtype) is required:

```
dtype=pd.ArrowDtype(pa.dictionary(pa.int16(), pa.string()))
```